# n -th derivative of $f(t)^{\alpha}$

Tags: derivatives

Im looking for a closed expresion for the $n$-th derivative of  $f(t)^{\alpha}$ with $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, that is:

$$\frac{d^n}{d\,t^n}f(t)^{\alpha}$$

Comment: Faa di Bruno's formula?

Comment: Yes, it's possible apply the faa di Bruno's formula. Any other way? I think there is a formula for n-th derivative of $f(x)^{g(x)}$...It's true?

Answer (score -1):

$\dfrac{d}{dt}(f(t)^{\alpha})=\alpha f(t)^{\alpha -1}f'(t)$

$\dfrac{d^2}{dt^2}(f(t)^{\alpha})=\alpha[f(t)^{\alpha -1}f'(t)]'=\alpha[(\alpha-1)f(t)^{\alpha -2}(f'(t))^2+f(t)^{\alpha -1}f''(t)]$

$\dfrac{d^3}{dt^3}(f(t)^{\alpha})=\alpha[(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)f(t)^{\alpha -3}(f'(t))^3+2(\alpha - 1)f(t)^{\alpha -2}(f'(t))^2+(\alpha - 1)f(t)^{\alpha-1}f'(t)f''(t)+f(t)^{\alpha-1}f'''(t)]$

Comment: Should be $g=f(t)^{\alpha}\Rightarrow \dfrac{dg}{dt}=\alpha f(t)^{\alpha -1}f'(t)$

Comment: No, $dg/dt=\alpha f'(t)f(t)^{\alpha-1}$ etc.

Comment: Mistake in the very first step, I'm afraid. And in every step after that, too.

Comment: To be specific: when you take the second derivative, you're deriving $f(t)^{\alpha-1}f'(t)$; you need to start by using the product rule $(a(t)b(t))'=a'(t)b(t)+a(t)b'(t)$ with $a(t)=f(t)^{\alpha-1}$, $b(t)=f'(t)$.  Every step after that suffers the same problem. You can see the discrepancy by taking $f(t)=t^2$, for instance.

Comment: Incidentally, this answer is still wrong (there are some arithmetic errors in the last line) and above and beyond that, it still doesn't answer the core question of finding a _general_ closed-form expression.